# Add factor column for POSIXct Date format

Tags: r, lubridate

I have the following `df` with the `Date` column having hourly marks for an entire year:

```
    Date                TD          RN          D.RN        Press       Temp        G.Temp.     Rad
1   2018-01-01 00:00:00 154.0535    9.035156    1.416667    950.7833    7.000000    60.16667    11.27000        
2   2018-01-01 01:00:00 154.5793    9.663900    1.896667    951.2000    6.766667    59.16667    11.23000        
3   2018-01-01 01:59:59 154.5793    7.523438    2.591667    951.0000    6.066667    65.16667    11.23500
4   2018-01-01 02:59:59 154.0535    7.994792    2.993333    951.1833    5.733333    64.00000    11.16833        
5   2018-01-01 03:59:59 154.4041    6.797526    3.150000    951.4833    5.766667    57.83333    11.13500        
6   2018-01-01 04:59:59 155.1051    12.009766   3.823333    951.0833    5.216667    61.33333    11.22167
```

I want to add a factor column 'Quarters' that indicates each quarter according to the 'Date'.
As far as I understand I can do that by:

```
Radiation$Quarter<-cut(Radiation$Date, breaks = "quarters", labels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"))
```

But I also want to add a factor column 'Day/Night' which indicates whether it's day or night, having:

Day → 8am - 8pm
Night → 8pm - 8am

It seems like with the `cut()` function there's no way to indicate time ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ifelse`/`case_when` statement after extracting hour from time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(Date), 
         label = case_when(hour >= 8 & hour <= 19 ~ 'Day', 
                           TRUE ~ 'Night'))
```

In base R :

```
df$hour = as.integer(format(df$Date, '%H'))
transform(df, label = ifelse(hour >= 8 & hour <= 19, 'Day', 'Night'))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
    mutate(hour = hour(Date),
           label = case_when(between(hour, 8, 19) ~ "Day", TRUE ~ "Night"))
```